# Let $G$ be a group and $H\le G$. If there exists a homomorphism $f:G\to H$ such that $f(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$, then is $H$ normal in $G$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If there exists a homomorphism $f:G\to H$ such that $f(h)=h$ for all $h\in H$, then is $H$ normal?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about group theory? Do you think the result should be true or false?

Comment: Think of semidirect products.

Comment: @Marcos I don't know $H$ is normal or not. In fact, I need it for another problem.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let's see. What is the definition of normal subgroup? $H$ is normal in $G$ if $g^{-1}hg\in H~\forall~h\in H, g\in G$. Since the only thing we have is $f$ there is only one reasonable path, which is to take some $h\in H,g\in G$ and to compute:
$$f(g^{-1}hg)=f(g)^{-1}f(h)f(g)=f(g)^{-1}hf(g)$$
Now, since we want to study if $g^{-1}hg\in H$ it is equivalent to study if $f(g)^{-1}hf(g)=g^{-1}hg$.

From here I let you do some work. What do you think? This seems reasonable? If the answer is yes, how can you prove it? If the answer is no, find a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll think of you questions.

Comment: A nice idea when you don't know if a result is true is to construct a couple of examples and study wheter the result is true or not in those examples. When those examples work it is also interesting to think if that is because the result is always true or because your particular example has an extra property that make thing work?

Comment: You're right. You've got a point there.  I understood your mean. I'll do what you said and then I'll write my result here. Thank you so much.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.